# JSSOR Slider not starting correctly or resizing in IE11

Tags: jssor

My slider @ http://idtestserver.pw/index.html (its the "Our Listings" section) loads and functions perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

When it load in IE11 it only shows one of the content blocks and does not autostart, if i click a slider nav arrow the listings show and the autostart begins as normal.

Also the slider does not resize in IE11

Answer (score 0):

Please always define width in pixel.

Replace

```
@media only screen
.small-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

with

```
@media only screen
.small-12 {
  width: 705px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick, I only needed to put a size on the container though, if i changed that css, id break my whole site :P (its a foundation framework)